# custom installer with auto update feature

Tags: .net, windows-installer

Is there option in .Net which can be used as a custom installer (which should have custom forms during installing, registry entry, etc.) with auto update feature.

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another free alternative for creating MSI packages fast and easy would be [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com), the "*Simple*" project type, the other ones require a commercial license. It has a VS add-in that automatically integrates when you install it, for VS 2010 and 2012, and also supports automatic command line builds.

It also has a Dialogs Editor, but this requires you register the application.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Visual Studio Installer Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked) on the Microsoft site. This is a large section with many articles.

If you want to modify the install interface have a look at this section: [Customizing Windows Installer Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2he6h0w)

Comment: I would not recommend a technology deprecated by Microsoft. When it is a legacy project you might have no choice, but in order to create the MSI packages from scratch it's not a good option.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko - it is not a recommendation it is an answer to the question as I assumed the OP wanted something from within Visual Studio rather than a third party

Comment: There are other options available from within VS, e.g. InstallShield Limited edition (out of the box) and WiX (installed separately)

Comment: @YanSklyarenko - this is a Q & A Site so feel free to post your last comment as an answer...